# What does a question mark in a filename matching pattern mean?

Tags: find, wildcards

What does the question mark in this command mean?

```
find . –type d –name "?d*" –print
```

I tried to to run it without it but didn't notice any change.

Comment: That is not regular expression, it is shell pattern. (See [Find and regex](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43913/find-and-regex) for similar confusion.)

Comment: Your command contains special characters (`“–`) rather than regular double-quotes and hyphens (`"-`).  Which ones are you actually using on the command line?  If the latter, please edit your post to correct.

Comment: The specific term for this is called globbing.

Answer (score 5):

The question mark matches exactly one character in a filename.  So,

```
find -name "c?t"
```

will match `cat` and `cot` but not `coat` or `ct`.

For what it's worth, this is a very common convention for filename matching, and can be used in a variety of command line interface contexts, even Windows' `cmd`.

Removing the question mark should make a difference unless nothing was matched anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern `"?d*"` in `find . -type d -name "?d*" -print` is interpreted by the find (as is correctly stated by depquid), not by the shell, and will match all the directories that have a second character `d` even if the first character is a `.`

For example, if there exist the directories `.dad`, `ada` and `xd`, the find command would print

```
./.dad
./ada
./xd
```

while the shell command `echo ?d*` (where the pattern ?d* is interpreted by the shell) would at least print (there would be and the names of any files matching the pattern)

```
ada xd
```

On the other hand if there are no directories with a second character `d` the find would produce no output in contrast to the shell command that would print

```
?d*
```

Answer (score 0):

The question mark is identified by the shell as a single character. In this case the name is specified as any directory with the second character of the directory name 'd', followed by any other characters.

`find` did not output anything because there were no directory names that matched the -name specification.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the shell isn't doing matching here; `find` is.  This makes a difference if you have `file1` and `file2` and try `find -name file?` instead of `find -name "file?"`, the former matched by the shell and the latter by `find`.

Answer (score 0):

`find . -name '?*.*'` will match "some(one)thing" then "anything" "dot" "anything"

Notes:

1. These are "find" search patterns, **not** bash glob expansions, and not regular expressions.
2. "anything" may include "nothing"

So the above will match any name.extension and .name.extension, but not an ".extension" without a name (or a name without an extension).

The "?d*" pattern in the question will match any name starting with any single character, followed by a "d".

Comment: The `-name` and `-path` predicates of `find` takes filename globbing patterns and they are exactly the same as what is used by default for globbing in e.g. `bash`. There isn't anything called "find pattern". Note too that the pattern would match names starting with a double dot, as in `..thing`. There isn't anything called "filename extension" either BTW, it's just names and they may have dots in them.